# "have widely been used" OR "have been widely used"?

Tags: present-perfect, word-order, auxiliary-verbs

Which word order is correct:

> "Psychological measurement tools *have widely been*  used in previous studies"

or

> "Psychological measurement tools *have been widely* used in previous studies "

I always used to suppose that only the first one was  grammatically correct, but now I am hesitant.

Comment: This is an issue of style, not grammar. There is no "correct" order between these two examples. The latter is more likely to be heard. To my ears, *have been used widely* would be preferable, but [it doesn't score as well in the corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+widely+been+used%2Chave+been+widely+used%2Chave+been+used+widely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20widely%20been%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20widely%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20used%20widely%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: There is no need to separate the perfect auxiliary and its complement, so "have been widely used" is fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Have been widely used** is far more common than **have widely been used**.  The reason is that **widely** modifies **used**, describing the widespread nature of the use.

Just the opposite occurs with "usually" and "seldom", where **have usually|seldom been used** are far more common than **have been usually|seldom used**. The reason is that **usually** and **seldom** modify the existential **been**, describing the frequency rather than the nature of the **use**.

Comment: I suppose that "rationale" makes sense, but it's interesting to note [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+been+occasionally+used%2Chave+occasionally+been+used&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20occasionally%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20occasionally%20been%20used%3B%2Cc0) showing how the preferred position for *have **been occasionally / occasionally been** used* has completely reversed over the past couple of centuries. The same thing happens with other adverbs, just not so strongly.

Comment: **Occasionally** or **on occasion** seem to me to straddle a semantic zone between pure frequency and particular purpose impinging on nature of use.

Comment: I understand the point you're making, but a similar shift occurred with [seldom](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+been+seldom+used%2Chave+seldom+been+used&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20seldom%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20seldom%20been%20used%3B%2Cc0) and [often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+been+often+used%2Chave+often+been+used&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20often%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20often%20been%20used%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: (But not with [widely](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+been+widely+used%2Chave+widely+been+used&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20widely%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20widely%20been%20used%3B%2Cc0), which seems to be something of a newcomer.)